# Node.js Store object in database or in array?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am developing a node.js multiplayer card game application, played by 4 players at the same time.

I have an array of object which contains all games in progress, 
I was wondering if 5000 games or more are in progress can I have memory problems with my server application ?

Would it be better for me to store the object in a database and read it each time, data connection will be a lot more used but memory less ? What is the best approach in this kind of situation ?

Comment: It all depends upon how large the data set is, how often you're accessing it and how much you need it to persist if the server goes down - none of which you have shared.  Memory is preferred unless the data size is too large for that or persistence is required or multiple process access is required.

Comment: In my example, the game object is accessed each ~15-20 seconds by each users (20 000 users in this case). I don't need data to persist in my example, "Memory is preferred unless the data size is too large", when should I consider the data size is too large ?

Comment: How large is the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can practically keep your data in memory, that will usually yield a solution that is faster and less complicated.

Here are reasons that you might have to use a database instead:

1. You need access from multiple processes.
2. You need persistence of data (if server should be restarted or crashes).
3. You are storing more data than will fit in memory.
4. You need certain concurrency or transactional features already built into typical databases.
5. You want to use certain searching/indexing features of existing databases.

If none of those reasons drive you to a database and the data comfortably fits into memory (for node.js probably less than 500MB-1GB) depending upon how much other memory your server uses and your server has access to enough run-time memory, then it's usually faster and simpler to store and access the data from memory.